# expand first div when second div or third div collapsed using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have three divs. Here is my code.

```
<div class="div1">Div1 Content</div>
<div class="div2">Div2 Content</div>
<div class="div3">Div3 Content</div>
```

Using jQuery how can I expand div1 if div2 or div3 collapsed?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @Sunit, inthis url when i try to close 2 or 3 or 4 div, it is not collapsed.

Comment: plz check my answer ... below live demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

Please check this [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/qhwgo6uy/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3>Div1</h3>
<div><p>Div1 Content</p></div>
<h3>Div2</h3>
<div><p>Div2 Content</p></div>
<h3>Div3</h3>
<div><p>Div3 Content</p></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
  });

  $('.ui-accordion-header').click(function(){
            if ($("#accordion").find(".ui-accordion-header-active").length == 0 ) {
         $("#accordion").find(".ui-accordion-header").eq(0).click();
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit after comment from OP [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qtz0t8o7/1/)

```
checkForDiv1 = function(){ // function to check the requirement and do things accordingly
    if($('.div.expand').length == 0){ // check for expand class div
        $('.div1').addClass('expand')
    }else{
        $('.div1').removeClass('expand')
    }
};

$('.div').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expand');
    checkForDiv1(); // check the requirement and do the required
});

checkForDiv1(); // call it to make it initially expanded
```

---

If you wish to go with your HTML and not modifying it, this can help

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qtz0t8o7/)

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $('div').not($(this)).removeClass('expand'); // you remove class expand from all except the one which is clicked
    $(this).addClass('expand') // add expand class to the one which is clicked
});
```

css

```
div {
  height:30px; // initial height required for transitions
  transition: all 1s ease // some smooth transitions
}
.expand {
  height: 200px;
  background:red; 
}
```

Comment: It is okay. When i try to close div2 or div3, then div1 should be open automatically

Comment: Thanks. Glad to help you :)